# Integration of a diverge function in c++ GSL Library

Tags: c++, integration, special-functions, gsl

I am trying to perform an Integral of Hypergeometric function `2F1(a,b,c,x)` from -1 to 1 for some good values of $a,b,c$ (lets say $a=1,b=2,c=3$) .

I did it in Python and Mathematica and the answer is finite although it is divergent at the point $x=1$. Anyway, I need to do this integration as a part of my very long code in c++.

I am using GSL (thank you! creators of this amazing library) to do so. Since this function is divergent at the upper bound of my integration ($x=1$), I used the `CQUAD` to calculate the integral; however because the output of Hypergeometric `2F1` for $x=1$ is neither `NaN` nor `Infinity`, I get the following error:

```
gsl: hyperg_2F1.c:685: ERROR: domain error 
Default GSL error handler invoked.
```

Any of you guys can help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you have tried QAGS instead of CQUAD?

Comment: Yes I have tried QAG, QAGS , QAGP and CQUAD.

Comment: Can you use the tanh-sinh quadrature in Boost.Math?

Answer (score 3):

I am not a frequent user of GSL, but I think I made it work by wrapping the hypergeometric function `2F1` provided by GSL in such a way, that it would return `NaN` for $x=1$. Then, the numerical integration will use this information for its purposes and the `domain error` will not be thrown.

So, (following the example provided in GSL docs) in function `double f` I compared the passed argument $x$ with a domain bound `sing_value` (don't judge the naming) in the floating-point sense. If they are sufficiently close, I return `NaN`, otherwise, I call the provided by GSL `2F1` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_hyperg.h>
#include <limits>


double f (double x, void * params) {
  double alpha = *(double *) params;
  double sing_value = 1.0;
  double diff = std::abs(x-sing_value);
  bool singular_point = (diff <= std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()*std::abs(x+sing_value)*2);
  // as per Kirill's comment, the comparison 
  // (diff < std::numeric_limits<double>::min()) 
  // is unnecessary for any practical sense.
  if (singular_point)
    return std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
  else
    return gsl_sf_hyperg_2F1(1,2,3,alpha*x);
}

int
main (void)
{
  gsl_integration_cquad_workspace * wcquad = gsl_integration_cquad_workspace_alloc (10000);

  double result, error;
  size_t nevals;
  double expected = log(16);
  double alpha = 1.0;

  gsl_function F;
  F.function = &f;
  F.params = &alpha;

  gsl_integration_cquad (&F, -1.0, 1.0, 0, 1e-14, wcquad, &result, &error,&nevals);

  printf ("result          = % .18f\n", result);
  printf ("exact result    = % .18f\n", expected);
  printf ("estimated error = % .18f\n", error);
  printf ("actual error    = % .18f\n", result - expected);
  printf ("# evaluations   = %zu\n", nevals);

  gsl_integration_cquad_workspace_free (wcquad);

  return 0;
}
```

According to Wolfram Alpha,
$$
\int_{-1}^1 {}_2F_1(1,2,3,x)dx = \ln 16
$$

which seems to be confirmed by the code

```
result          =  2.772588722239701653
exact result    =  2.772588722239781145
estimated error =  0.000000000000023683
actual error    = -0.000000000000079492
# evaluations   = 2553
```

The code is not optimized in terms of tolerances, subdivisions and, especially, it being an awful mixture of C/C++ for no reason.

Tested on gcc 6.4 and GSL 2.4.2

Comment: Nitpick (I only mention this because I think it's a common source of confusion, I hope it's okay): so long as `abs(sing_value)>1e-290`, the comparison `diff < std::numeric_limits<double>::min()` is always false and can be omitted. The smallest positive real double is almost counter-intuitively small. The comparison is in most cases equivalent to an exact comparison with zero, `diff == 0`.

Comment: @Kirill that's actually a very nice detail. I never (years!!!!!) bothered to get a sense of what I am comparing to, just did it based on what I think is right as opposed to reality.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slighly simpler solution to Anton's method. The GSL `hyperg_2F1` function will raise a domain error flag as well as set the return value to `NaN` for input values it doesn't like. The integration routines know how to handle `NaN` return values, so all you need to do is turn off the GSL error handler. This can be accomplished as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_hyperg.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>

double f (double x, void * params) {
  double alpha = *(double *) params;
  return gsl_sf_hyperg_2F1(1,2,3,alpha*x);
}

int
main (void)
{
  gsl_integration_cquad_workspace * wcquad = gsl_integration_cquad_workspace_alloc (10000);

  double result, error;
  size_t nevals;
  double expected = log(16);
  double alpha = 1.0;

  gsl_set_error_handler_off();

  gsl_function F;
  F.function = &f;
  F.params = &alpha;

  gsl_integration_cquad (&F, -1.0, 1.0, 0, 1e-14, wcquad, &result, &error,&nevals);

  printf ("result          = % .18f\n", result);
  printf ("exact result    = % .18f\n", expected);
  printf ("estimated error = % .18f\n", error);
  printf ("actual error    = % .18f\n", result - expected);
  printf ("# evaluations   = %zu\n", nevals);

  gsl_integration_cquad_workspace_free (wcquad);

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the output I get:

```
result          =  2.772588722239768266
exact result    =  2.772588722239781145
estimated error =  0.000000000000305493
actual error    = -0.000000000000012879
# evaluations   = 1565
```

Comment: nice trick. I wonder, why is the number of evaluations in your case so much lower than in mine with the same accuracy parameters.

Comment: I noticed that too and don't have an answer. If I had to guess, the `hyperg_2F1` function may return valid results even in cases where your `singular_point` test returns `NaN`.